# How to make SSL/https connection on development server?

Tags: https, development

I dont want to pay for certificate because its just for my development site can i install any certificate to enable encryption i dont care if browser going to warn against it or not as long ssl will work.

Answer (score 1):

Openssl can help you to build own CA (and server cert from thisCA) or just issue self-signed certificate

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can generate a localized cert to your website for testing purposes.  How you go about doing it will certainly depend on what web server you are going to use.

Comment: Generating doesn't depends from used webserver, only enabling on server

Comment: true but the process for generate is different from apache, to IIS, to nginx.  No??  Perhaps MrXEe can elaborate on the help they are requiring?

Comment: "true but the process for generate is different from apache, to IIS, to nginx. No??" - I'm not sure what you can't use prepared by 3-rd party cert+privkey files in IIS: never used IIS, and httpsin nginx also... can make mistake

Comment: it is like we are doubles partners vollying the ball to each other waiting for the other person on the other side of the net....